# Should profane user names be prohibited?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, display-names

I know that profanity is discouraged in SO posts.  However I recently saw a user with the F-word in his name.  Just out of curiosity, I searched for other users with the same word and found many hits - see below.

Personally this does not offend me.  I just wonder how others feel about it, and if it is something that SO should try to prevent.

Apologies if I've offended anyone by posting this image.

Edit - This questions is similar to, but not the same as: [Possibly offensive usernames](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117596/possibly-offensive-usernames).  That question asks about a particular name and if it is genuine or not.  I am asking if SO should be doing anything to prevent users from creating accounts with potentially offensive names.

[image]

Comment: Odd that this would be closed as a duplicate.  I thought I clearly explained why this differs from the other question.  Oh well...

Comment: One way you could extend the discussion, if you chose to, would be to post a feature request that SE actively prohibit some words in names. (I can't swear that this hasn't already been proposed, however; please search.) You could then refer to [Possibly offensive usernames](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/117596) as support for the proposal. A feature request will generate policy discussion as a matter of course.

Answer (score 10):

If you see user names like these on a post, or turn up in a user search, then I think you should flag one post from that user for moderator attention, and use a custom reason to say that you consider the name used by the poster to be offensive.

Comment: I just flagged a post I run into from user called "bleeched anus", obviously my flag was declined by moderator. because:  " flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention " so wtf

Comment: @Vickel if I had seen your flag on either site that I moderate, then I would have agreed with you.  My first instinct would be to reset the user's name and at minimum would have discussed mod messaging the user with my fellow moderators.  Perhaps raise whether that user name is considered offensive in the site-specific Meta of the site where you flagged it.

Comment: I'm a bit tired to bring things like that to meta, so I tried to just flag for mod's attention, but they seem too busy with content issues.... But maybe, you beeing a moderator on other sites could word that a bit better than myself?

Comment: @Vickel what site can the user be found on?  I'd like to have more context before crossing over to another site where I may not already participate.

Comment: on stackoverflow, I run into this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47253859/how-do-i-scroll-to-an-element-within-a-div-with-overflow-y, there I flagged: " don't like to answer to a user who calls himself "bleeched anus" or maybe stalin or hitler etc... (last 2 is just to make a point)" – Vickel 12 hours ago   declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention