# Allowed to use impolite nickname?

Tags: discussion, offensive

Is it allowed to use a impolite nickname like ShittyCoder? Or use the name of a politician known to be a dictator? See the nickname here: [ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3) // Werkzeug Debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40699176/1513933)

Can we flag this kind of thing?

Comment: [Flagging mechanism for offensive usernames](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107453/flagging-mechanism-for-offensive-usernames) answers your last question. I doubt whether using the username "Fidel Castro" is flag-worthy though.

Comment: Seems like the user chose to change their name when they were notified about it.

Comment: There's more than one person named Fidel Castro in the world.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Someone using obscenities in their name isn't acceptable, and you should use a custom moderator flag to point that out if you believe it should be changed. That is not the case in the example you provided here.

So, funny thing is that I believe Fidel Castro is that person's actual name. Even if it isn't, I don't believe Fidel Castro falls in the fairly narrow category of public names that we ask people to not use.

I declined your offensive flag on that post, because a general offensive flag carries heavy penalties and would be the wrong kind of flag to use, even if the name was a problem. Offensive flags carry no context, and cause us to review a post itself, not the user behind it. If you have a complaint about a user name, please use a custom flag and describe your issue with it.

Comment: Here is the main problem:  One person may find something offensive that someone else finds non-offensive.  If one was to go around banning names due to similarities to historical figures that did not due......erm.....positive things......anyone with Mao, Pol/Pot, Adolf, Heinrich, Hermin....yeah I think you get the picture......Heck things got bad on the game Cabal Online.....you could sell jewelry, but could not say jewelry in chat........due to the first three letters, all in the name of being non-offensive.